# Make UITextField accept small alphabet letter only in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I Want to Make textField that accept only small alphabet letter not capital alphabet letter or no any special symbol or not any digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression for it, in example below regular expression that allows only small symbols

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    let regex = "[a-z]{1,}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex).evaluate(with: string)
}
```

Comment: let me double check.

Comment: You also have to 1. make your "ViewController" class inherit from "UITextFieldDelegate" (so `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`) and then add `usernameTextField.delegate = self` to `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict Caps letters, Digits & Special symbols, return `false` other than small letters in text view delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`.

**Swift 3.0:**

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var myCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        for i in 0..<(string.characters.count ?? 0) {
            var c: unichar = string[i]
            if !myCharSet.characterIsMember(c) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: My question is only small alphabet letter are accept in textfield

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: let me double check.

Comment: Error in CharacterInMember.

Answer (score 1):

check this  updated code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:");
         NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }

        return YES;
    }

}
```

**in Swift**

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").invertedSet
        return string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(set) == nil

    }
```

Comment: if he understand the logic ,he can able to convert it @NiravD easily.

Comment: I'm just suggestion you to edit your answer rest is up to you .

Comment: ya ... I am helping him to resolve the issue ... :D thats it .. chill @NiravD

Comment: check now @SakirSherasiya

Comment: u checked @SakirSherasiya if u have any problem comment

Comment: i testing all answer.

Comment: value of type 'Charactedset' has a no memeber 'invertedset'

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code only getting small letters automatically.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textEntry: UITextField!

   //MARK : - Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       textEntry.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    //MARK: - Lower letter function
    func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = sender.text?.lowercased()
        print(textEntry.text ?? "") //Check your text output here
    }
 }
```

Comment: let me double check.

Comment: Ok check it first, surely it will work. @SakirSherasiya

Comment: It convert capital letter into small and i don't want it.

Comment: let me add this functionality. @SakirSherasiya

Comment: same it convert capital letter into small.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this too,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Return false when user tries to delete but textField is empty
    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount) {
        return false
    }

    // Return true when user tries to delete but textField is not empty
    if string == "" {
        return true
    }

    let userEnteredString = textField.text ?? ""
    let newString = (userEnteredString as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    return ((newString as String).range(of: "^[a-z]+$", options: .regularExpression) != nil)

}
```

Comment: let me double check.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to inherit the UITextFieldDelegate class with your own class

   `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {`
2. Add an IBOutlet

   `@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!`
3. You have to assure this object is using

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       firstName.delegate = self
   }

   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       if textField == firstName {
           let allowedCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
           let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
           let typedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
           let alphabet = allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharacterSet)
           return alphabet
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You have to use `UITextFieldDelegate`, not `UITextViewDelegate` (because you're using a TextField), otherwise there's an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'` Changing it to the suggested `self as! UITextFieldDelegate` then just throws a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.